# Including minified javascript in external php file

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

**Basic question:**

How to include a `script.min.js` in an external php file.

**My current setup:**

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js.php"></script>
```

js.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
include "script1.js"; echo "\n\n";
include "script2.js"; echo "\n\n";
include "script3.js"; echo "\n\n";
?>
```

**Long Question:**

I've ran into this issue a couple times over the years and ignored it by including it as a separate `<script src=""></script>` but it's time to find out if there is a solution.

Occasionally I'll run into a javascript file that doesn't work when included. Just produces javascript errors. (I've tried echo file_get_contents(...) also)

My current script is `tinymce.min.js`.
As above it works fine if included `<script src="tinymce.min.js"></script>` after my `js.php` file. But included in the php file does not work.

Shouldn't be relavent as it's not the first minified script to not work. But the current error recieved in Firefox console is `TypeError: c is not a constructor`

Side question, should I be using `Content-type: application/javascript` since I'm only catering for modern browsers?

Comment: Why would you concat your javascript files into `js.php` and at the same time lose all caching etc `

Comment: whats the goal here? seems like what you need is a build tool/process like grunt which is made for this sort of thing rather then a php hack

Comment: I really don't see how a normal <script> include could not work. Please give us an example of a setup not working.

Comment: @adeneo You are completely correct, I over looked caching. I was looking at raw load times, which is quicker due to only one request, not multiple scripts.

Comment: @atmd I wouldn't call it a hack (before the caching realization) it was merging files to save load times. But if there was a header to allow caching of php then this would work well.

Comment: @A.Rama the point was to eliminate potentially 20 <script> tags/loads instead just having one load. I only realised it wasn't being cached after being pointed out by adeneo.

Comment: I'd appreciate a reason for the down vote. It is a valid question how to include multiple scripts in a php file without errors.

Comment: A normal web pages opens tens of connections for scripts, css files, images and all sort of things and browsers are very fast and very good at doing this. If you "lose" time in the backend preparing the initial page, you're delaying the start of all these connections and you're probably making your page slower to display, not faster. Also you'll lose any caching advantage (and with CDNs nowadays almost all the main js libraries are cached).

Comment: @A.Rama thanks for the last comment. All the comments have been good. I'm thinking I'll go with versioning my scripts and including individual minimised versions of my them.

Answer (score 0):

With grunt you can easyly concat your js files and run the command   a concat setting is like this

```
concat: {
   options: {
   // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
   separator: ';'
  },
  dist: {
   // the files to concatenate
   src: ['src/**/*.js'],
    // the location of the resulting JS file
   dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
  }
}
```

so you can define your files you want to concat and also the destination

Comment: This looks kind of like a minimization package run to join different scripts to make an overall.js I'm looking to include already minimised scripts into a php page to the client only has to load the one page instead of many. The problem is some already minimised scripts produce an error.

Comment: this only concat files it not minified the files again . if u want minify you can do this also with grunt of course. And you can maybe use jshint in grunt to figure out why the minified files producing an error. Grunt is a JavaScript Task Runner.